# Function taking pointer-to-method regardless of constness

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I want to implement a generic function that will take reference to object and pointer to its member function and invoke it. However I'm not able to do so when my class has both const and non-const methods as I need to provide two overloads:

```
template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename ...Us>
Ret callMethod(Class &object, Ret (Class::*method)(Us...))
{
    return (object.*method)(Us{}...);
}

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename ...Us>
Ret callMethod(Class &object, Ret (Class::*method)(Us...) const)
{
    return (object.*method)(Us{}...);
}
```

Is there some way to write only 1 template function that will accept both const and non-const method pointers so I don't have to write my code twice? I'm using C++14.

For a broader picture, what I want to ultimately achieve is pass a 3rd parameter, a data buffer from which method arguments will be extracted - hence the template function to handle it as generically as possible.

Comment: If you only had one function template, which member function would you want to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C++14 alternative without using `std::function`.

> what I want to ultimately achieve is pass a 3rd parameter, a data buffer from which method arguments will be extracted - hence the template function to handle it as generically as possible

What you use at the call site will be perfectly forwarded here:

```
template<typename Class, typename Func, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) callMethod_impl(Class& object, Func method, Args&&... args) {
    return (object.*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Us, typename... Args>
Ret callMethod(Class& object, Ret(Class::*method)(Us...), Args&&... args) {
    return callMethod_impl(object, method, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Us, typename... Args>
Ret callMethod(const Class& object, Ret(Class::*method)(Us...) const, Args&&... args) {
    return callMethod_impl(object, method, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s8xYWj)

If you need `Ret` in `callMethod_impl`, just add it as a template parameter and call it like `callMethod_impl<Ret>(...)` from the `callMethod` overloads ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fczr9j)).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, don't implement this yourself, it has already been done for you in the form of [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```cpp
#include <functional>

struct A {
    void foo(int x);
    void bar(int x) const;
};

void example() {
    A a;
    std::invoke(&A::foo, a, 3); 
    std::invoke(&A::bar, a, 3); 
}
```

Seeing that you have added a C++14 tag in retrospect, the documentation of [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) has a sample implementation which you can use in your project.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately this does not solve my problem, as like I said I'm stuck with C++14...

Answer (score 1):

Without `std::invoke`, you can only do some more or less generic workarounds, based on type erasure. Using `std::function` allows you to create a proxy-function to treat your functions on an equal footing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename Ret, typename ...Us>
Ret callMethod_impl(std::function<Ret(Us...)> f) {
    // common implementation here
    return f(Us{}...);
}

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename ...Us>
Ret callMethod(Class &object, Ret (Class::*method)(Us...)) {
    return callMethod_impl(std::function<Ret(Us...)>(std::bind(method, object)));
}

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename ...Us>
Ret callMethod(const Class &object, Ret (Class::*method)(Us...) const) {
    return callMethod_impl(std::function<Ret(Us...)>(std::bind(method, object)));
}

struct Foo {
    int bar() const { return 1; }
    float bar() { return 2.1f; };
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    std::cout << callMethod(f, &Foo::bar) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that `volatile` functions (+ combinations) are not treated here, but maybe you don't need full generality but rather a pragmatic solution.